# Octave image update fails after output window resized

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm using octave to process some video and provide it's output on different processing stages. I'm loading video frame by frame and using `set(self.image_object, 'CData', self.data);` for image update.

After I resize output window, set function fails with `set: invalid handle (= -1.39375)`.

```
%fist frame display
self.image_object = imshow(self.data);

...

%new frame arrives and I try to set display it's content in already created image output
set(self.image_object, 'CData', self.data);
```

It seems like after output window is resized my `image_object` becomes invalid.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Which Octave version, which OS, which graphics_toolkit? Also a MCVE would be good

Comment: and for the record: I've used this method to view an image and then update it's content multiple times without problems. So you should really create a MCVE which shows the problem and also add the answer to my questions from the first comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know whether this answer worth leaving here, but the reason of a crash was subplot recreation. So in preudocode my program was quite similar to following:

```
loop
    imageA = get_updated_image_A();
    imageB = get_updated_image_B();

    create_subplot();
    display_image(imageA);

    create_subplot();
    display_image(imageB);
end loop
```

So in octave it was causing execution failure after output window was resized. After I changed my code in a following way, everything started to work as intended:

```
loop
    imageA = get_updated_image_A();
    imageB = get_updated_image_B();

    if(is_first_iteration)
        create_subplot();
    endif
    display_image(imageA);

    if(is_first_iteration)
        create_subplot();
    endif
    display_image(imageB);
end loop
```